# Input impedance of an electronic load

Tags: impedance, tvs, electronic-load

I would like to simulate a TVS with an electronic load working in constant voltage. I could add some resistor in serie with the electronic load to simulate the dynamic resistor of the TVS. Nevertheless if the input impedance of the electronic laod is higher than a TVS it seems to be a bad idea. Also the input impendance probably depends on how fast the electronic load is able to regulate the voltage after seeing a variation of current. It is probably a bad idea as I do not think that an electronic load is able to react as fast as a TVS, so its input impedance would higher than a TVS, isn'it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: "Electronic load" could mean anything from a simple basic component to a multi-IC programmable device. Response speed is not implied by the phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electronic load sinks current, a bench power supply sources current, but besides that... there is no fundamental difference in control loops implementation.

You need two loops, one for voltage and one for current, either nested or one overriding the other.

In fact, if the circuit has an output stage that can both source and sink current, like a push pull class AB or a synchronous DC-DC converter... the same circuit could work both as electronic load and power supply, with some tweaks maybe an extra opamp to control current in both directions.

So the same stability problems will occur in an electronic load and a bench power supply, in particular the user expects it to be stable and not oscillate no matter what kind of load is connected to it. I mean, if we can call "load" whatever is connected to the electronic load.

So a bench supply (or electronic load) will encounter all kinds of impedances: R, L, C, and combinations of it. The inductance of banana plug wires sets a limit, but it isn't much. To be stable, it must have an output impedance that doesn't form an unwanted peak with load impedance.

At DC, the output impedance will look like a very low value resistance. Since feedback systems have finite reaction time, the output impedance will always be inductive (ie, rise) at HF, and that tends to introduce problems with low value capacitive loads. Therefore, for stability, most of these circuits will have a small output capacitor with suitable ESR added in order to create a flat spot in the output impedance, with ESR providing damping, to enhance stability.

In addition most of these circuits require some turnaround time when switching from voltage mode to current mode, which can be substantial if an opamp has to slew or come out of clipping in order to do so.

This is pretty much the opposite from a TVS, which will have (compared to the electronic load):

- extremely fast reaction time (ns)
- much lower capacitance, especially if it's meant to protect signal lines, in which case it will be optimized for lowest possible capacitance.
- much lower inductance, because it's a small SMD component and not a large box connected with wires
- higher DC impedance, it's a passive component without feedback
- probably lower HF impedance

In particular, low inductance is required for the TVS to do what it's supposed to do, which is to catch fast ESD events.

So I guess the impedance of a TVS and an electronic load should be completely different...

Answer (score 1):

An electronic load in CV mode senses the load voltage to correct it to your set voltage.

As such, from basic feedback theory, the impedance at that voltage sensing place will be very low at DC due to the shunt feedback (I'm not considering the TVS diode in this situation).

However, this impedance increases at higher frequencies due to the drop in loop gain, so it has an "inductive' behavior.

Nonetheless, the transient suppression is the role of the diode itself, and not of the E-load. So, the node at which both TVS and E-load are connected is low at very high frequencies, due to the TVS itself.

Why would you want the E-load to react as fast as the TVS if it's the TVS suppression capability the one you want to test? Sounds like your test setup idea is fine.